# jBCrypt just prepends the salt to the hash

Tags: hash, bcrypt

I'm using jBCrypt for the first time, I'm not using Spring in my project and don't want that heavy library for the one simple thing, BCrypt.

My understanding is a salted hash involves the salt being combined with the password and THEN hashing it. The results of using this library, however, show that the final hash appears to basically be the salt pre-pended to the hash.

This is my test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String salt = BCrypt.gensalt();
    System.out.println("SALT: " + salt);
    String pass = "passwordpasswordpassword";
    String hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, salt);
    System.out.println("HASH: " + hash);
}
```

This is the output:

```
SALT: $2a$10$gJ9JwqTC0jNJEhX3IUl7je
HASH: $2a$10$gJ9JwqTC0jNJEhX3IUl7jeo18wnF1AgMjQha78sFA/c5Mubx49j6q
```

This just weirds me out. I'm wondering if I'm using the library wrong, or if I'm just misunderstanding the way BCrypt is working for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the expected behavious of BCrypt. There's no need to keep the salt secure. It's important that it's user specific. The salt is needed internally by the BCrypt.checkpw function to be able to compute the hash for the password the user has entered and compare it to the hash you have stored.

Also see: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt